# Unix shell scripting: assign value from file to variable into while loop, and use this value outside the loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, while-loop

I'm writing a shell script, where I have to extract the contents of a file which is of type:

> type1|valueA
>   type2|valueB
>   type1|valueC
>   type2|valueD
>   type3|valueE
>   ....
>   typen|valueZ.

For each type in `column_1`, I have a target variable, which concatenates the values of the same type, to get a result like this:

> var1=valueA,valueC
>   var2=valueB,valueD
>   var3=valueE
>   .....

Script implements something like this:

```sh
var1="HELLO"  
var2="WORLD"  
...  
cat $file | while read record; do  
   #estract column_1 and column_2 from $record    
if [ $column_1 = "tipo1" ]; then  
   var1="$var1, column_2"  ## column_2 = valueB
elif ....  
....  
fi  
done
```

But when I try to use the value of any of the variables where I chained `column_2`:

```
    echo "$var1 - $var2"
```

I get the original values:

```
    HELLO - WORLD.
```

Searching the internet, I read that the problem is related to the fact that the pipeline creates a subshell where the actual values are copied.

Is there a way to solve this problem!?

Above all, there is a way that would fit for all types of shells, in fact, this script must run potentially on different shells!?
I do not want to use file support on which to write the partial results.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `cat`. Piping something into `while` creates a subshell. When the subshell exits, the values of variables set in the loop are lost (as would be directory changes using `cd` as another example. Instead, you should redirect your file into the `done`:

```
while condition
do
    # do some stuff
done < inputfile
```

By the way, instead of:

```
while read record
```

you can do:

```
while IFS='|' read -r column1 column2
```

Answer (score 2):

BASH FAQ entry #24: ["I set variables in a loop. Why do they suddenly disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: All persons who begin writing shell scripts should be required to read through the entire BASH FAQ once, just to head-off the inevitable questions.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
for a in `awk "-F|" '{print $1;}' test | sort -u` ; do echo -n "$a =" ; grep -e "^$a" test | awk "-F|" '{ printf(" %s,", $2);}' ; echo "" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$2:a[$1] OFS $2}
END{for (i in a) print i"="a[i]}' FS=\| OFS=, file  

type1=valueA,valueC
type2=valueB,valueD
type3=valueE
```